# regex expression contains a word and does not contain another

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex expression that would be give the line that does not contain google but contains com

For Example:

```
www.google.com
www.msn.com
www.msn
```

it should match `www.msn.com` because it contains com and doesn't contain google.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can use `^(?!.*google).*\.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead regex for your requirement:

```
^(?!.*google).*\.com
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r7i3Jt/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*google)`: Negative lookahead to assert we don't have `google` ahead
- `.*\.com`: Match `.com` after `0` or more characters

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, appreciated :)